# Cannot access Microsoft Graph List Messages API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant, microsoft-graph-mail

I try to get my user's mail information using List messages API(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

I am following the instructions described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service.

I registered my application, configured "Application Permissions" to able to use **List Messages**, got administrator consent using

```
 // Line breaks are for legibility only.
 GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MY_TENANT_NAME}/adminconsent
 ?client_id=MY_APP_CLIENT_ID
 &state=12345
 &redirect_uri=https://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

And giving my credentials I could get **admin_consent=True** url. And then I could get an access token using

```
// Line breaks are for legibility only.

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MY_TENANT_NAME}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=MY_APP_CLIENT_ID
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET_KEY
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I have a valid access token. I can see my users calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users.

However when I call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{MY_USER_ID}/messages, I got an error message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '2a862810-93dc-4096-a6b0-dda413670497' does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ba60c495-742b-4655-be74-fe8802427756",
      "date": "2020-04-11T19:20:32"
    }
  }
}
```

Interestingly when I use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, I can get my user's email. I have checked the queries but it does not seem any difference. The only difference that I saw, when investigating 
AAD --> Enterprise Applications --> Permissions,
I can see user consent permissions in Graph Explorer application, but not in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that it complains over your tenantID. However, under AAD Registered apps,

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps

check if you have Mail.Read* permission set.

Comment: The required permission have been set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using correct app id as in your ad app there are three type of ID's: Application ID, Object ID and Directory ID. Here you have to use Application ID.

You can also verify the AppID in your access token

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct Application ID. The problem is that even if I granted admin consent to my admin account, it is something like MY_NAME#EXT#@MY_TENANT_NAME.onmicrosoft.com, I cannot see my accounts when I call **users** api

Answer (score 0):

How many active directory environments are there in this tenant?Are you sure you are creating the Azure AD app in the correct tenant?

I believe you maybe using the wrong tenant id. The user id exists in that tenant, but the mailbox does not.

In aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/… there is the tenant id property which you should use in the oauth url - login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}

Double check you are using the correct one.